# How to call addEventListner on this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('selector') where el is elementRef

Tags: angular

I am using angular 5 and have simple requirement where I need to create some html within a function and then loop it to bind click event to them.

**Earlier I was doing:**

**userslist.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
enter code here
 constructor(private el: ElementRef){}

createUserList(){

    this.userList= _cityList.map(list => {
      return `<li class="list-users" >${list.display_name}<span class="hide" >${list.name}</span></li>`;
    }).join('');

this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('li.list-users').forEach(ele => {

 ele.addEventListener('click', this.selectUsers.bind(this));
}
```

}
With this I get error in IE:

> ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

So I updated it to:

```
  const listUsers= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".list-users"));

        listUsers.forEach((ele) => {
          ele.addEventListener('click', this.selectUsers.bind(this));
        })
```

this worked in IE and other browsers. But I don't want to use document to access DOM elements.

If I write:

```
   const listUsers= Array.from(this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".list-users"));

        listUsers.forEach((ele) => {
          ele.addEventListener('click', this.selectUsers.bind(this));
        })
```

Then I get error in tslint:

> Property 'addEventListener' does not exist on type '{}'

Output of both this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".list-users") and document.querySelector is same.

Then why Array.from not converting former to array.

Need help in fixing this with angular way and not using document object directly.

output I get from both:

```
NodeList(5)  0:li.list-users
1:li.list-users
2:li.list-users
3:li.list-users
4:li.list-users
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: <li class="list-users" >${list.display_name}<span class="hide" >${list.name}</span></li>. Five such list elements. updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, stop using vanilla JS.

Angular is a full framework that also supports dynamic DOM manipulation through its `Renderer`.

Second of all, in this case, you should instead use a `ViewChildren` decorator, along with the renderer.

[**This stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flsxb2?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) shows you how it works. Open your console and click on the items.

```js
import { Component, Input, Renderer2, QueryList, ViewChildren, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let i of [0, 1, 2, 3]" #listItems>Index is {{ i }}</li>
      </ul>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  @ViewChildren('listItems') listItems: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLUListElement>>

  constructor(private R: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.listItems.toArray().forEach((item, index) => {
      this.R.listen(item.nativeElement, 'click', () => {
        console.log('You clicked on the item n° ', index);
      });
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks trichetriche But I am dynamically creating html. I have updated my question. thanks. will it work with that too?

Comment: @Simer well the answer is the same : stop doing it vanilla JS style and use Angular to dynamically create your list elements.

Comment: I get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined. May be it is because I am creating html with a function and then calling toArray on it within that function and code is running async and by that time html is not ready.

Comment: If you kept your way of doing it, then yes, it is normal. As I said, you should put your list items in the template and use Angular to populate it. Look at the stackblitz and append your data to it, this will be easier to understand.

Comment: But I don't want them in template they generate dynamically. Yes I have checked stackblitz and it is working fine. but my requirement is little diff. no. of li generates dynamically on basis of some result which I fetch from server so every time I have diff no. of Li items. that is why generating li items within component function. Sorry but I don't know how I can do it angular way.

Comment: You can do it with `*ngFor`. If you install angular and don't use it, then you shouldn't install it in the first place ! Consider reading the documentation about that, or maybe switching frameworks (jquery, react or vue for instance)

Comment: trichetriche I need one more help. If you can tell me how I can bind particular function to click event of liItems. As I did earlier in my question. I am trying to implement your solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177814/discussion-between-simer-and-trichetriche).

Comment: I'm on phone sorry, I can't chat. But you simply have to replace the console log with the function you want ! It can even be a function in your component.

Comment: Oh sorry I asked a wrong question. I know how to do that. Thanks for the help. God bless!

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ViewChildren and Renderer2 listen method to handle click event. Here is the stackblitz code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzduhs

Comment: Instead of copying an existing answer, consider upvoting it. Duplicates aren't useful.

Comment: I don't say you copied it, I say it's the same answer. And if it's the same answer, you should consider upvoting an already existing one, instead of posting the same answer. That's just common sense ...